# Field grouping in SolrNet?

Tags: solr, filtering, solrnet, facet

I am trying to make a query in solr.net that generates a solr query with a filter query with more than one term in it e.g.: `fq=Size:(4 large)`

However, when I pass `?f_Size=(4 large)` in the query string to the SolrNet sample app (found here: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/downloads/list), no results are found.

Looking at the logs, I can see that the filter query generated is `fq=Size:"\(4+large\)"` so it makes sense that no results are found.

Is there a way in SolrNet to generate a filter query with more than one term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the filter queries are built, try replacing `Query.Field(...).Is(...)` with `Query.Simple(...)` (you have to build the query yourself). See the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/DSL) for reference.